# Passing a column as a function parameter that creates a table

Tags: postgresql, function, parameter-passing

I need to create a function that will generate a table.
This table will have columns brought with several left joins.
At some point i need to filter the data based on the value of a dynamic column (i need to have: WHERE table_name.dynamic_column_name = 1)(that column has 1s and 0s, i need to keep only the 1s)
So when I 'call' the function, user should type like this: `SELECT * FROM function_name(dynamic_column_name)`

What i did:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION check_gap (_col_name varchar)
   RETRUNS TABLE ( ... here i have several columns with their type ...)
   LANGUAGE plpsql
AS $function$
     BEGIN
        RETURN QUERY
        SELECT ... a bunch of columns ...
        FROM ... a bunch of tables left joined ...
        WHERE _col_name = 1;
    END;
$function$
;
```

- I even tried with table_name._col_name .. though it wasn't necessary, the query (select from) works just as fine without
  ** I found some solutions for dynamic value but not for a dynamic column
  *** I am using PostgreSQL (from DBeaver)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need dynamic SQL for that. Pls. note that the code below is SQL injection prone.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION check_gap (col_name varchar)
  RETURNS TABLE (... several columns with their type ...) LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$$
BEGIN
  RETURN QUERY EXECUTE format
    (
     'SELECT ... a bunch of columns ...
      FROM ... a bunch of tables left joined ...
      WHERE %I = 1;', col_name
    );
END;
$$;
```

Comment: To avoid serious issues with SQL injection, you'd better use format() or quote_ident() to get the column names in safely.

Comment: @FrankHeikens fair enough, answer updated

Comment: I am not sure what is the issue, but: one of the columns i need in my table is: CONCAT('Type ', table3.col2). This is supposed to to create a column containing values: Type A or Type B. I just used the above suggestion and i got this error: SQL Error [42703]: ERROR: column "Type " does not exist
  Where: PL/pgSQL function check_gap(character varying) line 3 at RETURN QUERY

Comment: Probably you passed NULL or an empty string as a parameter?

Comment: i'm calling like this: select * from check_gap('sl_45'). The issue seem to be: due to me using (') before SELECT ... and again in the CONCAT(' ') ... code interprets as a break in code (i'm just assuming, of course) ... how can i bypass this issue?

Comment: Solved my issue by escaping the '' (by adding another set of '' ... like CONCAT(''Type ''). 2 single quotes, not double quotes. Btw I had to also change the type of some of my columns in the return table () part. It did not like what i added... fortunately the description of the error was also suggesting the proper type. Thank you!